# Big query regular expression - remove comma in double quotes

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

Basically I need to split json string and select particular attributes (after unnest)

Keys and values are unknown
`{"date":"2011-01-01","ok_key":"ok_value","ok_key2":"value2","key3":"no_okay,str_2"}`

I tried:

- split by comma, not work because of comma in string
- use regex to replace comma in string, but RE2 implementation in Big query doesn't
  support lookbehind

I have an alternative now is to :

```
replace(json_query(attributes,"$"), '","', '"|separator|"')
```

which creates my own separator to replace the 'good' comma, then I can split using this separator I defined..

Is there a way to replace the comma between double quotes in Big Query? Just curious.

Desired output is 2 string columns:

Col_Key, Col_Value
"Date",  "2011-01-01"
"ok_key", "ok_value"
"ok_key2","value2"
"key3", "no_okay,str_2"

My workaround now is
`split(translate(replace(json_query(bada_json_str,"$"), '","', '"|separator|"'),"{}",""),'|separator|')`

it is not working perfectly because JSON value say INT type may don't have double quotes surrounded

Comment: what the expected output? also, do you know in advance the key names?

Comment: Whenever you give an example please show the desired result. It may be clear to you but may not be to readers. Do you wish to split the string on commas that are not within double quotes?

Comment: To split the string on commas that are not within double quotes you can match the following regular expression: `(?:^|,)([^,"]*(?:(?:"[^"]*")[^,"]*)*)(?=,|$)`. The matches between the commas not within quoted strings are saved to capture group 1. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/S6XJdx/1)...

Comment: ...For your example, the matches from capture group 1 are as follows: `{"date":"2011-01-01"`, `"ok_key":"ok_value"`, `"ok_key2":"value2"` and `"key3":"no_okay,str_2"}`. Hover your cursor over parts of the regular expression at the link to get a description of their function. This should work as long as positive lookaheads are supported.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly the point. Big Query RE2 implementation doesn't support lookahead lookbehind..   I solved with my clumsy replacing of the 'good' comma and 'good colon'

Answer (score 1):

Use below

```
select key, value
from data, unnest(bqutil.fn.json_extract_keys(attributes)) key with offset
join unnest(bqutil.fn.json_extract_values(attributes)) value with offset
using(offset)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Have you tried? did it work for you?